# r count number of retweets

Tags: r, twitter

For a given user, I want to count the total number of retweets he obtained for all his tweets in a given time startdate to enddate.

For example, if user John has twitted 100 tweets from 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-30, and if 30 of those 100 tweets got a total of 60 retweets till now, then I want to extract that value 60.

I have seen a related answer by @Ben [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427147/retweet-count-for-specific-tweet).

A code snippet would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: **Moderator Note** I've cleaned up the comments. Should you feel the need to continue discussion the merits of the question, then take it to chat. In the meantime if you find this off-topic then vote to close, but stop arguing in the comments and @john don't remove the content of the post again.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I came up with. Each tweet has a "retweetCount" attribute. Just sum those...

Also, note that the twitter API only supplies tweets for the last couple weeks or so. Historic Twitter data is available from various resellers. `userTimeline` accepts tweetIDs for min and max, instead of dates, so you'd have to do a little work to get the date range you are looking for.

```
a <- userTimeline("corynissen", n=100)
> sapply(a, "[[", "retweetCount")
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
[77] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

> sum(sapply(a, "[[", "retweetCount"))
[1] 8
```